# Anchor with background-position not displayed, a Firefox bug? - Solved: Adblock Plus blocking Google anchor

Tags: html, css, firefox

All day long I am trying to find the source of the following problem.

I am using this HTML:

```
<div class="sharebox">
    <a class="shlink tooltipS" title="trumpa nuoroda į šį puslapį" href="http://www.klaustukai.lt/5"></a>
    <a class="shprint tooltipS" title="spausdinti" href="javascript:window.print();"></a>
    <a class="shfb tooltipS" title="dalintis Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.klaustukai.lt"></a>
    <a class="shgp tooltipS" title="dalintis Google+" href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.klaustukai.lt"></a>
    <a class="shtw tooltipS" title="dalintis Twitter" href="https://www.twitter.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.klaustukai.lt"></a>
</div>
```

with this CSS:

```
.shlink, .shprint, .shfb, .shgp, .shtw {
    position:absolute; 
    display:inline-block; 
    background:url(http://www.klaustukai.lt/qa-theme/kt/elements.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    border:0; 
    height:16px; 
    width:16px; 
}
.shlink {background-position:-2px -250px;left:4px;top:5px;}
.shprint {background-position:-22px -250px;left:27px;top:5px;}
.shfb {background-position:-40px -250px;left:50px;top:5px;}
.shgp {background-position:-58px -250px;left:73px;top:5px;}
.shtw {background-position:-76px -250px;left:96px;top:5px;}
.shlinktxt {display:block;width:115px;margin-top:30px;}
.shlinktxt input {font-size:10px;color:#555;width:100%;}
```

where `elements.png` holds the graphics for the background. Nothing special, nothing fancy. And works for years in all browsers.

The weird thing: When I do a test in a separate test.html it works fine, even in Firefox 27.0.1. But having the exact same code in this forum: [klaustukai.lt](http://www.klaustukai.lt/2499/ar-butina-darbo-sutarti-registruoti-registru-centre) will not show the google plus button class `.shgp`.

This happenend after the last update of Firefox to version 27.0.1. Before it worked! This is why I think it might be a Firefox bug. In Chrome and Internet Explorer displaying the button works as expected:

[image: IE11]

**Firefox 27.0.1**

[image: Firefox27]

What I see from the Firefox developer tool **Box Model** is that the `.shgp` element has height:0 and width:0 - it also seems to have lost position, the indicator shows it now top left on the website.

I also tried to reposition the sharebox, I disabled javascript, same problem, it is always the `.shgp` anchor that fails.

When testing, I realized that if I save the HTML page locally and load it again in the browser, the button is displayed correctly. Even more confusing.

This is such a weird issue for me. Who knows what is causing this behaviour? And how can the `.shgp` anchor be displayed correctly?

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: `background:url(http://...)` string must be used in quotes: `background:url('http://...')`

Comment: @DanFromGermany: That's not true.

Comment: @DanFromGermany I have put the quotes now, same behaviour.

Comment: @DanFromGermany: *"The format of a URI value is 'url(' followed by optional white space followed by an **optional single quote (') or double quote (") character** followed by the URI itself, followed by an optional single quote (') or double quote (") character followed by optional white space followed by ')'. The two quote characters must be the same."*

Comment: @Careless ok you are right. I shut up, it's friday, have a nice weekend :)

Comment: @EchtEinfachTV it works on my firefox version 27.0.1, on the provided site it does show the G+ button; could it be a cache issue?

Comment: Oh that is even more strange. I am running 27.0.1 portable. Might that be the reason? Maybe the update for the portable version did something unexpected. I am trying a fresh install. Reporting back in 5 min. PS: No cache issue. Cache has been emptied.

Comment: Doh... it works on the fresh installation. I cannot believe that. What a time waster on Friday... hope others running in the same problem will read this, before spending hours on this issue! Thanks for your help.

Comment: FYI: It was Adblock Plus! See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Found the source of the problem!

The culprit has been the [Addon Adblock Plus](http://www.adblockplus.org) that is blocking the google plus anchor!

If you disable the addon the button appears.

Cannot believe... but now everything gets more clear. I installed Adblock Plus on Chrome and the button disappeared as well. Good to know that it is **not** a Firefox bug.